# How do i get withRouter work in my child component which is not configured as route

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-redux, higher-order-components

I just want to perform some usual operation. When I click on the logo of my site it should take me to the Main Page. Whether I am on a third page of the website, after clicking on the logo I should be able to see my main component. It is a react-redux application. I tried withRouter Higher Order Component to access its history.push() method but I am getting an error of "Cannot define withRouter() outside the router." I tried all its solution but it is showing me that error anyhow. What approach will help me here to make that routing work?? Is there anything specific to import in redux store? Logo component is my child component, which is not included in route configuration.

```
Content.js 

const Content = (props) => {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Demo 1} />
            <Route path="/demo2" component={Demo 2} />
            <Route path="**" render={() => (
              <Redirect to="/" />
            )} />
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

Header.js

    class Header extends Component  {

     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
       }

      render(){
      return (
        <div  >
          <div >
            <img src="/images/logo.png" />
          </div>
          <div className="header">
            <span className="logout-btn">logout</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }}
    export default Header


App.js

> class App extends Component {   
render() {`

    return (

      <div className="wrapper">
        <Header />
        <Content></Content>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to click on the image (which is in Header Component) and I want Demo 1 Component to be rendered as it is my homepage.

Comment: Are you wrapping your app with `<BrowserRouter/>`? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: Post your code, thanks.

Comment: @wdm I tried to wrap it with BrowseRouter too but still did not work.